# How to control what markers are displayed by mapbox-gl-js

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I am loading a bunch of geojson points. I can see that I am loading about 40 points but which ones get displayed on my map seems random and somehow connected to the zoom level. Below you can see that only 2 points of ~40 are displayed.

[image: markers from geojson]

What criteria does mapbox-gl-js use to decide what to display?

Is there a way to control what points are being displayed? (All of them? Some based on an attribute?)

Comment: maybe is it because of the allow-overlap option?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely occurring because you are using the default `text-allow-overlap` value of `false`. The [`text-allow-overlap` documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#layout-symbol-text-allow-overlap) reads

> If true, the text will be visible even if it collides with other previously drawn symbols.

Because your symbols overlap each other, some are hidden. You can disable this behavior by setting `text-allow-overlap` to true.

You might find [marker clustering](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/) to be useful.